Web error when connect smart contract on website for dapp
Web component code:
const bidSubmit = async () => {
    const bidValueEth = parseFloat(bidAmount); 
    if (isNaN(bidValueEth) || bidValueEth <= 0) {
        setBidError('Please enter a valid bid.');
        return;
    }

    if (bidValueEth <= parseFloat(price)) {
        setBidError('Your bid must be higher than the current bid.');
        return;
    }

    console.log("Bid origin price", bidAmount);

    const bidValueWei = web3.utils.toWei(bidAmount, 'ether'); 
    try {
        if (petAuction && account) {
            await petAuction.methods.bid(tokenId).send({ from: account, value: bidValueWei });
            console.log("Bid successfully：", bidValueEth, "ETH");
            bidClose(); 
            setBidAmount(''); 
            setBidError(''); 
        } else {
            setBidError('The contract is not loaded or the wallet is not connected.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Bid failed：", error);
        console.log("Bid account：", account);
        console.log("tokenId:", account);
        console.log("Bid bidValueWei:", bidValueWei);
        console.log("Bid price:", price);
        console.log("petAuction address:", petAuction);
        setBidError('Bid failed, please ensure the bid is higher than the current maximum bid and that the auction has not yet ended.');
    }
};

Web console error:
Web3ValidatorError: Web3 validator found 1 error[s]:
value at "/0" is required
Smart contract code (bid function):
    function bid(uint256 tokenId) external payable nonReentrant {
        Auction storage auction = auctions[tokenId];
        require(auction.active, "Auction is not active");
        require(block.timestamp >= auction.startTime && block.timestamp <= auction.endTime, "Auction is not in active period");
        require(msg.value >= auction.reservePrice, "Bid must be at least the reserve price");
        require(msg.value > auction.highestBid, "There is already a higher or equal bid");

        address previousBidder = auction.highestBidder;
        uint256 previousBid = auction.highestBid;

        auction.highestBid = msg.value;
        auction.highestBidder = msg.sender;

        if (previousBidder != address(0)) {
            (bool success, ) = previousBidder.call{value: previousBid}("");
            if (!success) {
                // if refund failed, user can refund manually
                failedRefunds[previousBidder] += previousBid;
            }
        }

        emit BidPlaced(tokenId, msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

This web component is used to call contract Bid function to bid for an auction. When I click the submit button in website, the web console post the error above.

Does it work when calling the function on etherscan? what about without the web component but on backend directly?
